# Dryer plug won’t go in

Tags: electrical, dryer

[image]----------
My 4 prong dryer plug won’t go all the way in. It’s jammed on the longer one. Any ideas of what could be the problem?
[image]

Comment: Turn off the breaker and see if anything is in there.  If the plug or receptacle are new, there might be a mismatch of size, but this is rare.  It might also just need a good push(if you have not tried), this is a good sign that the connections are tight.

Comment: hold the connector next to the wall plug to check if the power outlet is too shallow

Answer (score 2):

From this prospective of the photo it looks like the back prong (12 o'clock) is bent.

Use pliers to bend it straight.

Comment: You mean the L shaped prong nearest OP's fingers?   That definitely matches the L shaped hole in the wall socket.   The wire/cord will point straight up in this config.

Comment: @Criggie I said 12 o'clock, the L shaped is 3 o'clock

Comment: sorry for confusion - I was taking the time orientation off the fixed side, not the plug photo.